# How To know whether an app which is installed from play store has used my android application or not

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I have an application that allow user to download an android app(any random app) from Google play store. Now, I want to store the information(in my database) that a particular application is downloaded from my application and not directly from play store.

I tried using few checks on back press(like enabling or disabling of flag when we come back from play) but they fail in some scenarios like download failed or slow download etc.

Please help me out solving this major issue.

Comment: You aren't clear. Where you want store this info?

Comment: please explain .do you want to keep track if user landed to play store through your app and pressed download button on Play Store app?

Comment: Hey Rahul. Please add more details to your question. It's not clear what you're trying to say. What do you mean by 'checks on backpress' ? Are you the owner of the other app that's being downloaded ? If so, then you can use the install referrer API.

Comment: @Godfather, yes as you said I want to keep track of whether user has landed to play store through my app and pressed download button on Play Store app and along with this if something happens like download failure then how to manage that thing.

Comment: @UmangMathur, By 'checks on back press I meant that' when I come back from google play store I enabled(TRUE) a flag if package is installed else disable(FALSE) flag.  Also, I am not owner of other apps that's being downloaded, It can be any random app.

Comment: @AbnerEscócio I want  to store that info in my database so that I can use that information for detecting whether an app is installed from my application or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as a referral check, app developers use it for things like checking if the app was installed from an ad. You can find more details about the [Play installer API here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/igetinstallreferrerservice) and [the library for using it here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library)

3rd party applications which do this (eg advertisers or rewards apps) will normally co-operate with the app developer to include some code in their app. The referral code check then runs in the App developer's app, not the 3rd party app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I thing this is used only when we are the owner of other apps on play store which we want to download. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Spying on installs of other apps which have not chosen to co-operate with you is not something supported by Google, it might be a breach of user privacy.

Comment: I can understand what your are trying to say, but their must be some way to do what I asked for as many applications like laddoo has done this before.

Answer (score 0):

just use `com.android.vending`

I use this in my React native project

here is the reference : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896154/getinstallerpackagenamestring-string-is-deprecated-deprecated-in-java/78238044#78238044)